# sumar registros por dia de la semana en curso - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy implementando ChartJS en mi proyecto pero tengo un problema a la hora de pasar mis datos al grafico.

**ChartController**

```
 $startWeek = Carbon::parse(Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->toDateString());
 $endWeek = Carbon::parse(Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()->toDateString());
 $weekReport = Payment::whereBetween('date_pay', [$startWeek, $endWeek])
                            ->select('date_pay', 'amount_pay')
                            ->sum('amount_pay');
```

se que este método me obtiene los registros por semana y me los suma, pero busco que cada día tenga su propia suma, para poder mostrar las sumas totales por dia.
la columna `date_pay` tiene un formato yyyy-mm-dd

Gracias de antemano

Comment: No se como será traducido a métodos del laravel, pero en sql estariamos hablando de una claúsula `GROUP BY date_pay` por si te sirve de algo.

Comment: @masterguru su recomendación me ha servido para entender como re formular mi consulta, muchas gracias he encontrado la respuesta a mi problema

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro :-)  Si no es mucha molestia puedes poner tu mismo la respuesta con tu solución a la pregunta, así no quedará pendiente eternamente (y al cabo de 48 horas la puedes aceptar y así tendrá más visibilidad) o bien puedes eliminar la pregunta para no dejarla pendiente (yo prefiero ver la respuesta, asi tambien aprendo laravel, pero tu decides)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno con base a la recomendación de `masterguru` de utilizar `orderBy` replantee mi consulta y en vez de utilizar `orderBy` utilice `groupBy`
pues buscaba agrupar los registros por dia.

primero realice una consulta SQL para obtener los datos que requiero

```
$weekReport = Payment::select(array(
                            DB::raw('DATE(date_pay) as date'),
                            DB::raw('SUM(amount_pay) as count'),
                        ))
```

posteriormente implemente `groupBy` para organizar mis registros por fechas

```
->whereBetween('date_pay', [$startWeek, $endWeek])
                            ->groupBy('date')
```

finalmente para usar toda la consulta con ChartJS utilice el metodo `pluck`

```
->pluck( 'count');
```

espero y si alguien tenga el mismo o parecido problema con esto pueda solucionar su problema